# Looking for lively sans-serif fonts with relatively short x-heights

Tags: font-recommendation, font-pairing

I’m looking for a sans-serif font that I can pair with [Bembo Book](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/bembo-book).

I’ve tried quite a few so far, and it’s pretty clear that the sans-serif needs to have a cap height to x-height ratio similar to Bembo Book (otherwise it just looks ungainly by comparison), and a vaguely calligraphic influence too, or at least some contrast between thick and thin lines (otherwise it colours the page differently, and looks quite stark.)

I can’t find any sans-serif that satisfies both those requirements. Does any exist? It can be a paid font.

[image: Bembo Font]

Comment: Are you looking for a display face or a book face?

Comment: A family that includes styles for both, preferably, but I'll settle for a book face.

Answer (score 1):

The [Optima Family](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/optima/family-pack) seems to fit the bill pretty well. Variable width strokes, similar cap height to lc ratio, and a large variety of weights to choose from. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**[Futura](http://www.identifont.com/show?O73)** is a classic with a modern look, not outdated, very versatile, has many different weight and styles too and I guess it could be considered lively. Not really calligraphic I suppose.

[image: Futura font family]

And there's **[Mesmerize](http://www.1001fonts.com/mesmerize-font.html)** that is a bit less straight and more calligraphic, and what I also consider lively.

[image: Mesmerize font]

And **[Kabel](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/kabel/)** if you want more curves and angles!

[image: Kabel families]

[image: Kabel Font 1]
__

**Opinion:** If you use Bembo for the body text, it looks good and adds contrast to use a thin condensed sans-serif or a demi/bold one that doesn't look too heavy, and play with the font size.

For example, below is a sample of **ITC Franklin Gothic Book** and Bembo.

[image: Franklin gothic and bembo font]

...and **ITC Franklin Gothic Demi**

[image: ITC franklin gothic demi and bembo]